# robot framework-unable to select a certificate in the browser pop up window

Tags: windows, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, registry, robotframework

I am using robot framework 4.1.3 with Pycharm and chrome browser and Windows 10 machine.
How do I select a certificate in this browser window?

[image]

I tried below multiple ways:

```
   Sleep 5s
${message}= Handle Alert action=ACCEPT timeout=2s
Press Keys ${None} ENTER
Press Keys ${None} \\13
Press Key css=body \\13 # ASCII code for the Enter key
Press Key css=body ENTER
Press Key xpath=//body ENTER
Press Key xpath=//body \\13
Press Key xpath=//body enter
Press Tab
Press Tab
Press Enter
```

Also tried to install SendKeys package to use below code but failing package installation -

```
import SendKeys

def send_enter_key():
    """
    Sends ENTER key to application
    Works only in Windows
    """
    SendKeys.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

I tried to add registry entry and able to see entry added in registry but still it is asking to select certificate in chrome browser

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls]
"1"="{\"pattern\":\"www.web.com\",\"filter\":{\"ISSUER\":{\"CN\":\"AC Representacion\"}}}"
```

Is there any option in robot framework to auto select certificate in chrome browser? or auto set certificate for website url? or set during driver launch?

Comment: I tried below registry code as well. I am using window machine-

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls\1 = {"pattern":"https://[*.]gov.us","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"AC Representacion","SUBJECT":{"CN":"Y4795129B ALESIA LEE PINNEY (R: B67140871)"}}}

Comment: Also tried ......Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls\1  = {"pattern":"*","filter":{}}
But not able to see entry in chrome://policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is correct answer after lots of attempts -

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls]
"1"="{\"pattern\":\"*\",\"filter\":{\"ISSUER\":{}}}"
```